# How to have an element with multiple backgrounds without solid color messing with transparent pngs?

Tags: css

I have a fluid element (variable width according to resolution) containing text with a green background. On each side of this element I have a PNG image with a complicated shape using the same green.

I want the text to slightly overlap on both PNG on each side. Is it possible to do this using only multiple backgrounds, or do I have to have 3 elements and use absolute positioning (complicated)?

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

You can use background-position css property or you can as stated have absolute positioning with negative margin.
However, without looking at how you have coded it may depend on whether its a background-image or a image block.

Comment: But how can you prevent the solid color from "drowning" the transparent areas of PNGs?

Comment: you will have to add a background color, so if it is a <img src="your.png" style="background-color:white;"> or you have to change your png to the color you would like it. Otherwise add a background color to the body or another div that comes before that one.

Comment: alternatively look into using a gradient.